# How to write curl post command output to text file

Tags: curl

I want to write curl post command output to text file which are highlighted in red box or either full output.
[curl output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyuTa.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In Linux/Unix, you can do this by redirecting the output to a file.

$> curl http://yoursite.com/index.html > target.file 
$>cat target.file